# find max score in binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The problem is to find the maximum score in a binary tree, where each node in the tree has a score. There is only 1 limitation, you can either only use the (direct) leaf nodes or the root node, but not both, e.g in the image, either use 2 or 4+5, but if you decide to use 4+5, 2 cannot be used, but 1 is possible because it is not the root of node 4 and 5.

What algorithm could find the maximum score?

[image]

Comment: So what is the maximum score in this example? 5?

Comment: no, that would be 4+5+1+3=11.

Comment: What if the 2 was 42 instead? It's neither the root nor a leaf, so it can't be used, right?

Comment: Why can you use both 1 and 3, and what's your mistake in 4+5+1+3=11?

Comment: yeah sorry, 4+5+3=12. By using 3, you cannot use 1.

Comment: How did you determine that 4+5+3 results in the maximum score? *That* would be an algorithm for finding the maximum score.

Comment: what do you mean? My question is how you would design an algorithm that could find the maximum score.

Comment: What is a "direct" leaf node. Do you have a definition of a non-direct leaf node? Do I understand correctly that in the set of selected nodes there may not be a pair that are in a parent-child relationship? Is that a correct description of the rule?

Comment: Any chance you will come back to us? Is this the correct interpretation? I posted an answer and would appreciate some feed back.

Comment: @trincot. I reformulated my problem in another post, but my question remains unanswered. If you'd like to help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161235/maximum-sum-of-nodes-in-binary-tree-such-that-no-two-are-adjacent-with-names

Comment: I will look at it later, but could you first assess the answer to your *current* question, which asks for *"What algorithm could find the maximum score?"*, which I believe I have answered?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the rule is that the set of selected nodes (for calculating the sum) may not have a pair of nodes that is connected by a single edge.

So that means that for a given (sub)tree you should consider the following sums:

- The root's value added to the recursive sums for the **grandchildren subtrees**, and
- The sum of the recursive sums for the direct **children subtrees** -- so excluding the value in the root node

Then choose the maximum from these two possibilities.

Here is some code you could use for that:

```
def maxsum(node):
    if not node:
        return 0
    total = node.value
    # Add maximum sums from the grandchildren's trees:
    if node.left:
        total += maxsum(node.left.left) + maxsum(node.left.right)
    if node.right:
        total += maxsum(node.right.left) + maxsum(node.right.right)
    # Get the sums from the children's trees and choose the maximum:
    return max(total, maxsum(node.left) + maxsum(node.right))
```

You could add memoization to improve the efficiency. You can simply prefix the function with these lines to achieve that:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache
```

Warning: when using this memoized variant, it is required that nodes are not mutated between multiple calls.

Comment: Typo: `total1`. Caching like that might be a little dangerous, if they modify the tree and call the function again. And [suggestion](https://tio.run/##XZDBCsIwDIbvPkXAgysOEbyIsIMnn2PYdCus7Ugz0aefXTqZW07hS/j5kv7DbfCXa0/jqNGAq99xcIUPGtVtB6msAR8YJpLBVIQ8kIezAA5cd1DJyulVdwMK3sNd6ynQusFBSo1gKDjgFqGh2utnaztN6A8RmBBjjjeBQCZgfY7s0HCZW7JNy4tGcpPVhSw@x@p3jKxIioLjGkqemnUfyCK3Vt1aQjJPMISIMp8PzArzXxIrxKL8f@hWYblIqXH8Ag).

Comment: Fixed the typo, and added a disclaimer. Thanks.