# Maximum sum of nodes in Binary tree such that no two are adjacent with names

Tags: python, data-structures

As the title says, im trying to find the maximum sum of nodes in a binary tree where i cannot take the values of the adjacent nodes. For a full explanation of the problem: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-sum-nodes-binary-tree-no-two-adjacent/?ref=lbp

What is want to achieve is to list the names of the nodes that contribute the maximum score, e.g my node class contains a name field, such that i can generate a list of nodes that create the highest score. How could i generate this list?

My code:

```
# Python3 program to find maximum sum in Binary
# Tree such that no two nodes are adjacent.

# Binary Tree Node

""" utility that allocates a newNode
with the given key """
class newNode:

    # Construct to create a newNode
    def __init__(self, key, name):
        self.data = key
        self.name = name
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def maxSumHelper(root) :

    if (root == None):
    
        sum = [0, 0]
        return sum
    
    sum1 = maxSumHelper(root.left)
    sum2 = maxSumHelper(root.right)
    sum = [0, 0]

    # This node is included (Left and right
    # children are not included)
    sum[0] = sum1[1] + sum2[1] + root.data

    # This node is excluded (Either left or
    # right child is included)
    sum[1] = (max(sum1[0], sum1[1]) +
            max(sum2[0], sum2[1]))

    return sum

def maxSum(root) :

    res = maxSumHelper(root)
    return max(res[0], res[1])

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = newNode(10, 'a')
    root.left = newNode(1, 'b')
    root.left.left = newNode(2, 'c')
    root.left.left.left = newNode(1, 'd')
    root.left.right = newNode(3, 'e')
    root.left.right.left = newNode(4, 'f')
    root.left.right.right = newNode(5, 'g')
    print(maxSum(root))
```

Comment: _Keeping track of names:_ When getting the highest score, you can probably keep track of a list of node names, then pass it upwards, appending the current node's name to it each time. This can be achieved by `return sum, root.name` and `sum1, names = maxSumHelper(root.left)` etc. Also, I would suggest that you use self, not root.

Comment: I very strongly advise you not to name one of your variables `sum`. This is already the name of a builtin function in python, and shadowing builtins can have unexpected consequences.

Comment: @LarrytheLlama `self` would be proper if the function were a method of the node class, but it's not.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ack. Also, when I said `root.name` I meant `[root.name] + past` to properly keep track of past nodes.

Answer (score 0):

int Sum(TreeNode *tree) {

if(tree == NULL) return 0;

return (tree->val + Sum(tree->left) + Sum(tree->right));

}

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31389432)